# I am trying to read a xml file to edittext

Tags: android

I dont know why my code wouldnt display on my edittext, can someone help?. I really need this to work.

I created my xml as a menu under the folder res\raw. I dont know if reading the file is the problem. I want the edittext to display at runtime/oncreate

```
public class CreateTreasureActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText      name;
    private EditText      clue1;
    private EditText      clue2;
    private EditText      clue3;
    private EditText      answer;
    private EditText      location;
    private EditText      point_value;

    FileOutputStream myFile;
    XmlSerializer serializer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_treasure);


        name       = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);          
        name.setText("");

        clue1       = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.clue1);          
        clue1.setText("");

        clue2       = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.clue2);          
        clue2.setText("");

        clue3       = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.clue3);          
        clue3.setText("");

        answer       = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer);          
        answer.setText("");

        location       = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.location);          
        location.setText("");

        point_value       = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.point_value );          
        point_value .setText("");
        // create the initial xml document if it already does not exist
        try 
        {
            File filename = new File(getFilesDir(), "treasure.xml");

            if(!filename.exists())
            {
                myFile = openFileOutput("treasure.xml", Activity.MODE_APPEND);

                // create a new XmlSerializer objectÂ 
                serializer = Xml.newSerializer();

                // use myFile as your xml serializer and set to UTF-8 encoding
                serializer.setOutput(myFile, "UTF-8");

                // Write <?xml declaration with encodingÂ 
                serializer.startDocument(null, Boolean.valueOf(true));

                // set indentation optionÂ 
                serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);

                // start a new top level tag and other tags
                serializer.startTag(null, "Treasure");
            }
            else
            {
                // use myFile as your xml serializer and set to UTF-8 encoding
                myFile = openFileOutput("treasure.xml", Activity.MODE_APPEND);

                // create a new XmlSerializer objectÂ 
                serializer = Xml.newSerializer();

                // use myFile as your xml serializer and set to UTF-8 encoding
                serializer.setOutput(myFile, "UTF-8");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Exception::",  e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.create_treasure, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onSaveButton(View v)
    {
        try
        {   
            // start a new top level tag and other tags, for our FINAL project, Contact could be Treasure Item
            // we don't need to have nested <Treasure> followed by Items, the format can be similar to the below
            // this way, we don't need to add an end tag for outermost element

            // create tags and values
            serializer.startTag(null, "Items");
            serializer.startTag(null, "treasure");
            serializer.startTag(null, "name");
            serializer.text(name.getText().toString());  // retrieve name entered by user from text field
            serializer.endTag(null, "name");

            serializer.startTag(null, "clue1");
            serializer.text(clue1.getText().toString());
            serializer.endTag(null, "clue1");

            serializer.startTag(null, "clue2");
            serializer.text(clue2.getText().toString());
            serializer.endTag(null, "clue2");

            serializer.startTag(null, "clue3");
            serializer.text(clue3.getText().toString());
            serializer.endTag(null, "clue3");

            serializer.startTag(null, "answer");
            serializer.text(answer.getText().toString());
            serializer.endTag(null, "answer");


            serializer.startTag(null, "pointValue");
            serializer.text(point_value.getText().toString());
            serializer.endTag(null, "pointValue");
            serializer.endTag(null, "Treasure");
            serializer.endTag(null, "Items");

            // perform the write by flushing
            serializer.flush();

            // clear the text fields
            name.setText("");
            clue1.setText("");
            clue2.setText("");
            clue3.setText("");
            answer.setText("");
            location.setText("");
            point_value.setText("");
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // use logcat to display errors
            Log.e("Exception::",  e.getMessage());
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I see here is the code for saving data that are in ur EditText written by the user into your treasure.xml file. This might not work yet, because your

```
 public void onSaveButton(View v)
```

is nowhere called.

It should be called, when you want to save the from user written data to storage. So you might add another Button that calls onSaveButton(); add the end of your OnCreate(...) method. Also you might change the paremeter View v to an empty one because I don't see its necessarity here:

```
Button saveButton = new Button(this);
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onSaveButton();
    }
});
```

If you want to read data from treasure.xml, use File**Input**s, not Outputs:

```
FileInputStream in = openFileInput("treasure.xml");
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}
```

And inside the while() {...}-loop you have read in every single line from the treasure.xml into a String called line. 
So put into this loop what you want to do with the line. 
e.g. you could wait to see if the string is "", then u know the next lines will be the input for your EditText name until a line is "", so you could use.

If you just want to know how to save/load data from application to storage and just thought u can simply use an xml file to do so. You might better take a look on http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage for how to save/load to internal/external storage. (Your treasure.xml file is only at project directory of eclipse, not on your real device).

Comment: I removed the name.set to "" out still nothing in the edit text

Comment: Or should i be using set text instead of get text?

Comment: Im wondering about what you expect. I see code to write the Text from EditText that the user has written into them to your treasure.xml file. Are these texts not written into treasure.xml after your application has run and onSaveButton() has been executed?  Your onSaveButton() is by the way no where called.

Comment: So how do I call my onSaveButton? I have been working on this project for 2 days now. If you have anything that can help me please let me know. If I manually put in data for set text and run it, i can see the text in my edit text which is not what i want. I want the edit text to populate from the data i put in my teasure.xml.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help and effort, i will try it out.